# How to avoid overlapping error bars in matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I want to create a plot for two different datasets similar to the one presented in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43838738/5936342):

[image]

In the above image, the author managed to fix the overlapping problem of the error bars by adding some small random scatter in x to the new dataset.

In my problem, I must plot a similar graphic, but having some categorical data in the x axis:

[image]

Any ideas on how to slightly move one the error bars of the second dataset using categorical variables at the x axis? I want to avoid the overlapping between the bars for making the visualization easier.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can translate each errorbar by adding the default data transform to a prior translation in data space. This is possible when knowing that categories are in general one data unit away from each other.

```
import numpy as np; np.random.seed(42)
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.transforms import Affine2D

x = list("ABCDEF")
y1, y2 = np.random.randn(2, len(x))
yerr1, yerr2 = np.random.rand(2, len(x))*4+0.3

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

trans1 = Affine2D().translate(-0.1, 0.0) + ax.transData
trans2 = Affine2D().translate(+0.1, 0.0) + ax.transData
er1 = ax.errorbar(x, y1, yerr=yerr1, marker="o", linestyle="none", transform=trans1)
er2 = ax.errorbar(x, y2, yerr=yerr2, marker="o", linestyle="none", transform=trans2)

plt.show()
```

[image]

Alternatively, you could translate the errorbars after applying the data transform and hence move them in units of points.

```
import numpy as np; np.random.seed(42)
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.transforms import ScaledTranslation

x = list("ABCDEF")
y1, y2 = np.random.randn(2, len(x))
yerr1, yerr2 = np.random.rand(2, len(x))*4+0.3

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

trans1 = ax.transData + ScaledTranslation(-5/72, 0, fig.dpi_scale_trans)
trans2 = ax.transData + ScaledTranslation(+5/72, 0, fig.dpi_scale_trans)
er1 = ax.errorbar(x, y1, yerr=yerr1, marker="o", linestyle="none", transform=trans1)
er2 = ax.errorbar(x, y2, yerr=yerr2, marker="o", linestyle="none", transform=trans2)

plt.show()
```

[image]

While results look similar in both cases, they are fundamentally different. You will observe this difference when interactively zooming the axes or changing the figure size.

Answer (score 11):

Consider the following approach to highlight plots - combination of `errorbar` and `fill_between` with non-zero transparency:

```
import random
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# create sample data
N = 8
data_1 = {
    'x': list(range(N)),
    'y': [10. + random.random() for dummy in range(N)],
    'yerr': [.25 + random.random() for dummy in range(N)]}
data_2 = {
    'x': list(range(N)),
    'y': [10.25 + .5 * random.random() for dummy in range(N)],
    'yerr': [.5 * random.random() for dummy in range(N)]}

# plot
plt.figure()
# only errorbar
plt.subplot(211)
for data in [data_1, data_2]:
    plt.errorbar(**data, fmt='o')
# errorbar + fill_between
plt.subplot(212)
for data in [data_1, data_2]:
    plt.errorbar(**data, alpha=.75, fmt=':', capsize=3, capthick=1)
    data = {
        'x': data['x'],
        'y1': [y - e for y, e in zip(data['y'], data['yerr'])],
        'y2': [y + e for y, e in zip(data['y'], data['yerr'])]}
    plt.fill_between(**data, alpha=.25)
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. This idea, however, is not well-suited for my problem. All the variables are categorical and I cannot have lines connecting them.

Comment: @revy Categorical or numerical - does not matter. They are just labels. Change integers with any objects of your choice and you will get exactly the same figure with different labels next to X or Y axis. For example, replace `list(range(N))` with `N` words - `alegria`, `desgosto`, etc. That easy.

Comment: Great answer! I love that way of defining your data as a dictionary. I'll do it always like this myself from now on!

Answer (score 0):

Threre is example on lib site: https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/lines_bars_and_markers/errorbar_subsample.html
[enter image description here](https://matplotlib.org/stable/_images/sphx_glr_errorbar_subsample_001.png)

You need parameter errorevery=(m, n),
n - how often plot error lines, m - shift with range from 0 to n

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).